# What value should be initialized in hints parameter of getaddrinfo()?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, unix-socket

In the `hints` parameter of `getaddrinfo()`, there is a pointer to the `addrinfo` struct, but what value should I initialize in the `addrinfo` object? In the `addrinfo` struct, there are several values that can be set, but in many resources there are 3 types of information that must be init in the example below:

```
struct addrinfo address_info = {
   .ai_family;
   .ai_socktype;
   .ai_flag;
};
```

Is there any other value that needs to be set?

Comment: OT: But please don't tag multiple languages, only the one you're actually working in.

Comment: The `hints` argument is just that: Hints that the resolver can use to select the wanted address information. You don't need all three fields, you don't even need to pass this argument at all, and leave it as a null pointer if you don't have any specific preferences.

Comment: With the above said, if you only want IPv4 addresses then set `ai_family` to `AF_INET`, and if you only want IPv6 then use `AF_INET6`. If you want TCP then use `SOCK_STREAM` as the socket type, etc. For any field you don't want to use, just set them to zero (which will be default if you omit any field in the initializer).

Comment: If you are doing network programming, then I can recommend Beej's Guide to Network Programming: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/index.html

Comment: There's a built-in command called `man` that prints a complete explanation of each system call. `man getaddrinfo` brings up `getaddrinfo`'s description, and, right there at the beginning there's a complete description of the third parameter and what every field in there does, when passed as a third parameter. What, specifically, in the `getaddrinfo`'s man page is unclear?

Comment: And if you are not in a system that has the `man` command, there are online versions, such as https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html